# Use of double colon (::) as a sentence separator

Tags: punctuation, non-standard

I know that the double colon (::) has been used in computing languages (e.g., [in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926866/), [Julia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/59102aa21e1b37cd116f12553876937dd080dcb1/base/docs/basedocs.jl#L3177-L3208), and [R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35243471/)), though its uses are [not limited to computing](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Double_colon).  However, in recent years, I have seen this more commonly used in every-day grammar, within certain contexts.

Particularly in email subjects and video titles, I have noticed the double colon being used in a similar way to the pipe (| [`U+007C`]), to break it up, almost denoting a subtitle.  For example:

> Olivia Rodrigo :: Vampire
>
> Dune | Official Trailer

Where, in academic writing, a full stop, dash, or colon would have sufficed, double colon (and pipe) seem to be growing in popularity (though the double colon is still certainly non-standard, and less used than the pipe).

Where did this convention come from?  Is there a preferred alternative to ::?

Comment: This isn't everyday grammar, it's typography used in lists, tables, or diagrams, not in actual English prose. Similar to many other uses of typographical symbols for decorative purposes. I think it's off-topic for that reason. Maybe you could discuss it on a design or typography forum.

Comment: Titles and email subjects are often abbreviated and don't follow normal grammar rules

Comment: This sort of doubled symbol is often used as a delimiter for lists and such specifically because it DOESN'T appear in standard English writing. It's safer to use for automated parsing by software or in markup languages such as markdown precisely because it is not used normally. People who see this sort of usage in source documents may start using it in casual communication, as for example when people started using the /s indicator for sarcasm, but that's more like shorthand than English.

Comment: That's halfway between hamburger and meatball. Pretty annoying if it isn't clickable. What is :: supposed to mean, that one of the several hundred characters easily available on a keyboard doesn't suffice for?

Comment: Like the double hyphen in The Waldorf⹀Astoria Hotel (now thankfully dropped), the 
 usage is non-standard as sentence punctuation. Email topic headings and video titles aren't limited to everyday grammar.

Comment: (possible) interest only: I use || to separate distinct thoughts in a comment field such as this one. || Using a double vertical separator is exceedingly non-standard but I think/hope/feel conveys its intended meaning well.

Comment: I've seen error messages in my browser relating to :: that refer to it with a Hebrew-looking name. Unfortunately, I can neither remember that name nor trigger the error!

Comment: @EdDaniel That would probably be T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM, an internal token name in the implementation of PHP which used to show up in error messages until version 8.0 https://3v4l.org/av2e0 And yes, it is based on Hebrew, as the lead developers of PHP for a while were Israeli.

Comment: @IMSoP Yes, that's the one!

Answer (score 10):

As a native English speaker who has been speaking and reading the language for most of my 65 years ... I am not aware of any accepted uses in ordinary writing of a double colon. (By "ordinary writing" I mean as opposed to computer languages, math formulas, and the like.) A writer may use it, of course, but any rules about its use and meaning are what that writer makes up. If there's any broad consensus on what it means, I'm not familiar with it and I'd guess most English speakers are not familiar with it.

Like any such unusual punctuation or other style, I'd say if you have a use for it, state what you are using it to mean up front. Like, "In this book, I use a double colon ("::") to connect section headings" or whatever. Just like, if you use a word with a non-standard definition, tell the reader. "In this article, I use the word 'computer' specifically to refer to an electronic device made with integrated circuits that ..." etc. If your meaning is obvious, or if it doesn't really matter, maybe you can get away without explaining. But err on the side of explaining.

Answer (score 4):

In logic and mathematics, `::` is an [analogy symbolism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogy#Analogy_symbolism) operator.  It's used to express a correspondence or comparison, and related questions, such as:

> dog : puppy :: cat : ?

…which is read as: “Dog is to puppy as cat is to what?”  (The answer in this case being ‘kitten’, of course.  I remember seeing many such questions in verbal reasoning tests in junior school.)

However, this is a fairly technical usage, and so probably doesn't apply to the quote in the question.  (As Jay, Stuart F, and barbecue point out, the symbol *doesn't have* a standard meaning in written English, and so it's free for specialised technical and typographic uses.)

Comment: Yes, I remember taking SATs in high school. Filled with questions like,  "hyperbola is to aardvark as Brazil is to ________".